# Is it possible to convert a bound script to a standalone script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I thought by using "Save a Copy" from a bound script, I would create a standalone version.

After I copied the script, I wasn't able to find the script from my Google Drive. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Did you add the Google Apps script app to your drive?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach I did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you "make a copy" of a bound script you end up with two script projects bound to the same container.

As far as I know the only option is to create a new stand alone script from scratch, re-create any files, and copy/paste the contents over manually.

Depending on your goal, another option is to keep the existing script container-bound, but access it as a library from a stand-alone script.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries

**2018 update:**

Google now offers an Apps Script API for remote management of Apps Scripts, and the CLASP utility for managing Apps Script from the command line.  You can now use these to copy the contents of a container bound apps script and populate a stand-alone script.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/

https://github.com/google/clasp

Comment: After further experimenting, I think you're right. Although this makes no sense and is pretty frustrating, especially given the number of files I have in  more complex add-ons. I don't really want to keep any scripts as container-bound, because it's easy to accidentally delete a document without remembering that it is a container. I'll just start most of my new projects as standalone projects from here on out.